# Magento - remove block using update XML

Tags: xml, magento, layout

How do I use a layout xml file to remove an already existing block? Specifically, I want to remove the block named "currency" from the block named "top.switches". It is being inserted in the directory.xml file, like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.switches">
        <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" before="store_language" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="optional_zip_countries" as="optional_zip_countries" template="directory/js/optional_zip_countries.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 39):

There are two methods to remove a block defined in one layout xml file, through another xml file:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.switches">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And the way you are conventionally expected to do it:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.switches">
        <remove name="currency" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

You can find an explanation of the various layout xml elements [here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/), but it doesn't cover the methods available to the action tag. For that, you need to look at the block class app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php, which features all sorts of useful functions such as unsetChild, unsetCallChild, insert, sortChildren, etc.

Answer (score 8):

add file named local.xml in your layout directory . then in local.xml you can remove any block with  "remove" tag . BTW the remove tag should be between "layout" and "default" 
then the file should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
   <default>
     <remove name="BLOCK_NAME" />
  </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: @CarComp Magento 1 and 2 are entirely different platforms with very different approaches to the layout XML, so you would be correct.

Comment: @CarComp You'd be suprised how much alike M1 and M2 are regarding the remove element: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html