# magento; diasble blocks on product page

Tags: magento

I have a slider on my home page. Thats correct but when I go to product page you see also the slider. Where can I turns this off?

I want it only on the home page.

Thanks!!

Use latest version of magento and the Magikshop theme from Themeforest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you installed the seperate extension for slider or it comes with your theme? If it was default provided by your theme.Then you can find the setting to configure the slider in

> "System->configuration" in your admin panel.

Search for the banner or slider you may get the setting there to select which page you want to show the slider.

The setting may be different according to the slider.

If you have installed the extension yourself then you may find the banner/slider menu in the admin panel.

Hope this will help.

Comment: It comes with the theme. It's not a extension. And I can't found any settings in my Configuration where I can it turn off for specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

If the slider is a widget, you should be able to specify the pages that show a widget instance. The widgets that are in use can be found in the CMS section of the Magento Admin panel.

If the slider is a block you probably need to disable/remove/unset that block from your product detail page. To disable block on a particular page, you need to edit your layout Xml file. These files are most probably found in the following folder:

```
app/design/frontend/THEME/default/layout/
```

How to unset a block is described, e.g. here: [Magento - remove block using update XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937018/magento-remove-block-using-update-xml)

Comment: This is the demo http://themeforest.net/item/shop-responsive-magento-theme/full_screen_preview/6868294.

Here you can see that the slider is only on the homepage and not at the product page, but on my website you see the slider on every page...:-(